# Setting focus on textbox after listbox additem

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

I have a simple form on Excel, with a couple information fields that are currently dragged from another previous form. There's only one textbox (txtEtiqueta) on which i input data using a handheld scanner. This data from my textbox, is added to a listbox using txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate() event. My problem is that i cant set the focus back on my txtEtiqueta textbox and i ought to get this, in order to keep scanning barcodes.

```
    Private Sub txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate()

            Me.ListBox2.ColumnCount = 7
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.txtEtiqueta.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 1) = Me.txtUsuario3.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 2) = Me.txtFecha2.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 3) = Me.txtConductor.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 4) = Me.txtPatente2.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 5) = Me.txtCelular2.Value
            Me.ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 6) = Me.txtEmpresa2.Value
            Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox2.ListCount


End Sub
```

Right after doing so, i set txtEtiqueta.value to null with another textbox_change event (which changes by counting listbox items)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
        Me.txtEtiqueta.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Finally, after cleaning txtEtiqueta values, i need to set focus back on it again, but i don't know how to achieve it. I have tried this, with no success:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
        Me.txtEtiqueta.Value = Null
        Me.txtEtiqueta.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Sadly, previous code line actually sets txtEtiqueta's value to null, but it does not sets focus on it.

Comment: If it is a 'form on excel' and you are adding code in excel, it is *not* VB.NET.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] as well as consult the usage guidance on the tags themselves

Comment: It is not clear if `txtEtiqueta` and `TextBox1` are the same control - is this the case ?

Comment: Robin. They are not the same control. Etiqueta is where i scan barcodes, and textbox counts items from a listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
        Me.txtEtiqueta.Value = Null
End Sub
```

will trigger the `txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate` event which is changing the value of TextBox1 and thereby triggering the `TextBox1_Change` event. This should be an endless loop which is broken somewhere. Perhaps VBA recognises that `txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate` replaces the existing value in TextBox1 with the exact same value on the second round and determines that no change has occurred. And perhaps you have some code elsewhere which you mention in your question but don't show. It doesn't really matter.

The solution to your problem lies in making sure that no events occur after you have set the focus back to `txtEtiqueta`. Use the `Application.EnableEvents` property for this purpose, perhaps like this:-

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.txtEtiqueta.Value = Null
        Me.txtEtiqueta.SetFocus
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

With this code you would prevent the `txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate` event from being triggered by setting its value to Null.

Comment: Hi Variatus, ty for your answer.
I have tried this code line with no success, watching how my form moves and also my code, i think the event  txtEtiqueta_AfterUpdate triggers before textbox1_change.

I also tried to set focus right after my data is added to listbox, but still not working.

Am i missing an event or something?

Comment: i'm even more confused now. I have this instruction added to my code:

`MsgBox ActiveControl.Name`

Right after adding data to my listbox, this instruction gets triggered and it shows that my focus is on txtEtiqueta, but, after i close it, i can see in form, that focus is set on submit button

Is focus same as a highlighted button?

Comment: Yes. When you click the submit button the code triggered by that button is executed and it gets the focus. I suggest that you turn off Application Events at the beginning of that code, set the focus on txtEtiqueta there and then turn events back on as the last command.

Comment: TY For your Help Variatus. Finally i have combined your explanation with tabstop on false for other indexes.
Now it works for me
Regards